# How do I add an on screen timer to my game?

Tags: tkinter, timer, stopwatch

So I'm making a game where I want to be able to time how long it takes to finish and display it in the window I'm using. The problem I'm running into is that once the code enters the loop, it gets stuck there rather than running the timer and the game at the same time. I've tried doing some research and using thread to make them run at the same time, but every time I try that it freezes and I have to kill the program. Any ideas on how to do this?

from tkinter import *
import time

```
root = Tk()

timer = Label(root, text="0", width=100, height=100)
timer.pack()

def new_game():
    # a bunch of game code
    start_timer()


def start_timer():
    timer_time = 0
    while timer_time <= 999:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer.config(text=str(timer_time))


new_game()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use while loop and `sleep()`.  Use `after()`.

Answer (score 0):

It was many times - use `after()` instead of `sleep()` and `while`

```
import tkinter as tk # `import *` is not preferred
import time

# --- function ---

def update_timer():
    global timer_time

    #timer['text'] = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    timer['text'] = str(timer_time)
    timer_time += 1

    if timer_time <= 999:
        root.after(1000, update_timer) # 1000ms = 1s

# --- main ---

timer_time = 0

root = tk.Tk()

timer = tk.Label(root, width=10)
timer.pack()

update_timer()

root.mainloop()
```